# Get only even(+odd) digits as output of a dataloader

Tags: pytorch, mnist, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to create a dataloader which outputs even and odd digits of MNIST (for multimodal VAE) in the form (0,1);(2,3);(4,5);(6,7);(8,9). I have written down a dataloader which outputs the same digits: (0,0);(1,1)...(9,9). But I am not able to make the digits even and odd separated by 1. Here is the code I have so far:

```
class JointDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, mnist_pt_path_1, mnist_pt_path_2):

        self.mnist_pt_path_1 = mnist_pt_path_1
        self.mnist_pt_path_2 = mnist_pt_path_2
        # Load the pt for MNIST 
        self.mnist_data_1, self.mnist_targets_1 = torch.load(self.mnist_pt_path_1)

        # Load the pt for MNIST 
        self.mnist_data_2, self.mnist_targets_2 = torch.load(self.mnist_pt_path_2)
        self.mnist_target_idx_mapping = self.process_mnist_labels()

    def process_mnist_labels(self):
        numbers_dict = {0: [], 1: [], 2: [], 3:[], 4:[], 5:[], 6:[], 7: [], 8:[], 9:[]}
        for i in range(len(self.mnist_targets_2)):
            mnist_target = self.mnist_targets_2[i].item()
            numbers_dict[mnist_target].append(i)
        return numbers_dict
        
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.mnist_data_1)
        
    def __getitem__(self, index: int):
        """
        Args:
            index (int): Index
        Modality 1: even digits
        Modality 2: odd  digits
        """
        mnist_img_1, mnist_target_1 = self.mnist_data_1[index], int(self.mnist_targets_1[index])


        indices_list = self.mnist_target_idx_mapping[(mnist_target_1)]
        # Randomly pick an index from the indices list
        idx = random.choice(indices_list)

        mnist_img_2    = self.mnist_data_2[idx]
        mnist_target_2 = int(self.mnist_targets_2[idx])
        
        
        return mnist_img_1/255, mnist_img_2/255, mnist_target_1, mnist_target_2
```

Comment: check data if digit is divided by 2, we use the remainder operator %

Comment: In which line do I check for that?

Comment: task: create a method for generating digits dataloader with options -only even -only odd

Comment: this you own code?

Comment: I can help to write a clean issue for you. the task is correct?

Comment: Yes, this is my own code. Please help me write a clean issue. I am working on the task

Comment: I am unable to do the task. How does one write such a method?

Comment: Are the even numbers supposed to be in `mnist_data_1` and the odd ones in `mnist_data_2`? Why are looking to output groups  `(0,1);(2,3);(4,5);(6,7);(8,9)`, isn't `(4,9)` not a valid *(even, odd)* pair?

Comment: Yes, even numbers supposed to be in mnist_data_1 and the odd ones in mnist_data_2. I am training a multimodal VAE for which i need this condition to be satisfied